# angular cors picking wrong port value

Tags: angular

I am trying to solve the CORS problem in my angular application.

I have my api, and for me to login I have to send a json through the post method to the site

http://localhost/bdevApi/api/index/login

my function to run http

```
doLogin(formulario) {
    this.http
      .post('/bdev/api/index/login', JSON.stringify(formulario))
      .subscribe( dados => this.afterAcess(dados), (error: any) => alert('erro'));
  }
```

**proxy.config.json**

```
{
  "/bdev/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost",
    "secure": "false",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

**package.json**
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",

so I run the server with npm start and when I try to login, it returns me the following error

```
POST http://localhost:4200/api/index/login 404 (Not Found)
```

the error occurs because the localhost of the api is on port 80 and not 4200, how do I resolve this?

Comment: You're proxying `/bdevApi` but calling `/api`, does that seem right?

Comment: is not it right to do so? Should I pass bdevapi / api?

Comment: Well you're proxying a path you aren't actually hitting in your app, what do you expect to achieve by that?

Comment: I edited the code, I want to be able to access my api without problems with the cors

Comment: Your proxy doesn't actually send traffic to a different port. Re-read the docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy